# How to convert a Python datetime.datetime.utctime() to an Obj-C NSDate, and back again?

Tags: python, objective-c, datetime, nsdate, utc

EDIT: Basically, I'm looking to do this, in UTC-time, ideally via ISO-8601:

1. Python: datetime.datetime ---> ISO-8601 string
2. Python: ISO-8601 string ---> datetime.datetime
3. Obj-C: NSDate ---> ISO-8601 NSString
4. Obj-C: ISO-8601 NSString ---> NSDate

---

This seems like it should be really simple, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Python code, converting to a string:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
'2012-03-08 00:07:31 '
```

Note that the time-zone info `%z` is printed as an empty string, since utcnow() returns a **naive** datetime object. How do I turn it into an **aware** one and get it to print like the following?

```
'2012-03-08 00:07:31 +0000'
```

On the Obj-C side of things:

```
// This fails and prints (null) since the timezone is missing.
NSString *pythonDate1 = @"2012-03-07 23:51:58 ";
NSDate   *objCDate1   = [NSDate dateWithString:pythonDate1];
NSLog(@"%@", objCDate1);

// This works, manually adding in the "+0000".
NSString *pythonDate2 = @"2012-03-07 23:51:58 +0000";
NSDate   *objCDate2   = [NSDate dateWithString:pythonDate2];
NSLog(@"%@", objCDate2);
```

Printout:

```
2012-03-07 19:14:47.848 Untitled 3[3912:707] (null)
2012-03-07 19:14:47.849 Untitled 3[3912:707] 2012-03-07 23:51:58 +0000
```

I'm not quite sure how to go back from an NSDate to a datetime.datetime object either. Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to deal with timezone objects, and your time is in UTC, why not just append the "Z" defining Zulu/Zero to the end as defined in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
'2012-03-08T00:07:31Z'
```

Unless of course Obj-C  doesn't support ISO-8601 formatting...

Or, if your still only going to use utcnow(), you can cheat and just add +00:00:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S +00:00")
'2012-03-08 00:07:31 +00:00'
```

Comment: It looks like it doesn't strictly support it, but only partially. It doesn't like the `Z`, but it will accept `+0000` and `+00:00` instead.

Comment: Again, if your only going to pass Obj-C utc time, you can cheat and just supply +00:00.  Otherwise I think your going to have to use pytz, like Phil mentions.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`datetime.now(tz)`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now) instead of `datetime.utcnow()` will get you an aware datetime object.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want the local time:

```
import datetime
from pytz import timezone

ET = timezone('US/Eastern')

now = datetime.datetime.now(ET)
now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

if you have a db or something that uses utc then:

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
ET.localize(now).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Python datetime to ISO-8601 String:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> now    = datetime.utcnow()
>>> string = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S +0000")                # Manually specifying ' +0000' since we know we have UTC time.
>>> 
>>> string
'2012-03-08T21:19:26 +0000'
```

**ISO-8601 String to Python datetime:**

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> string = "2012-03-08T21:19:26 +0000"
>>> time   = datetime.strptime(string, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S +0000")   # Only works for UTC time.
>>> 
>>> time
datetime.datetime(2012, 3, 8, 21, 18, 31)
```

**NSDate to ISO-8601 NSString:**

```
NSDate          *now            = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLocale        *locale         = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
NSTimeZone      *timeZone       = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];                                   // Using "en_US" for locale ?eliminates/reduces? issues with systems running different locales.
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];   // Explicitly re-stating default behavior for 10.4+.
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSString        *iso8601String  = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];

NSLog(@"%@", iso8601String);
2012-03-09T02:44:37 +0000
```

**ISO-8601 NSString to NSDate:**

```
NSString        *iso8601String = @"2012-03-09T20:37:49 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter  = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLocale        *locale         = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease];
[dateFormatter setLocale:locale];                                   // Using "en_US" for locale ?eliminates/reduces? issues with systems running different locales.
[dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];   // Explicitly re-stating default behavior for 10.4+.
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:iso8601String];

NSLog(@"%@", date);
2012-03-09 20:37:49 +0000
```